# Multidimensional array init without pre-existing values?

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array, initialization

How can we initialize a multidimensional array without pre-existing values? Only the third one is correct, but it works with pre-existing values. I would like my multidimensional array to contain 10 or 20 values, and add them later on with numbers[y][x] :

```
int[][] numbers = new int[10][];
//List<int[]> numbers = new List<int[]>();
//int[10][]{ new int[]{}};
//correct :  { new int[] {1, 2}, new int[] {3, 4, 5} };
numbers[0][0] = 58;
```

Would you know how to do this? (I don't know if `[,]` is the same as `[][]` by the way)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`Would you know how to do this? (I don't know if [,] is the same as [][] by the way)`*
there are not the some as  `int[][] test = new int[10][];` is called a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) (array of arrays) and int[,] is a fixed array

just declare your array as the following

```
 int[,] test = new int[10,30];    
test[0,1] = 10;
test[1,2] = 20;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Julie Shannon

Answer (score 1):

You can try initiating values this way, it is one way to create [jagged-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576759/what-is-a-jagged-array)

```
int[][] test = new int[10][];
test[0] = new int[20];
test[1] = new int[30];
test[2] = new[] { 3, 4, 5 };

test[0][1] = 10;
test[1][2] = 20;
```

Comment: Thank you very much AppDeveloper