# null reference Exception - i already initalialize it with object ,but still gives me null

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, nullreferenceexception

null reference Exception - i already initalialize it with object ,but still gives me null

```
 List<Json_mts400resultses>[][] Dmts400res = new List<Json_mts400resultses>[DSedObj_people.Count][];

if (jsonData2[0] == 'U') { continue; } /* if basic_auth error skip DSing */  

// here  is this is initializing wrong?
mts400res[i][j] = new List<Json_mts400resultses>();  


                          //  here gived me error at array      
DSedObj_X_Y_mts400res[i][j] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Json_mts400resultses>>(jsonData2);
  //jsonData2  brings everything
```

debugpic  array is like this..! 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Oyx.png

**Solved:** i switched from **mts400res[i][j] TO mts400res[i,j]** 
now flows like oil ---SOLVED.--–

Comment: You'll have to give us more than that. Which variable is causing this error, and what have you tried?

Comment: i tried to write but it says mustly code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576759/what-is-a-jagged-array

Comment: i switched from ** mts400res[i][j] to   mts400res[i,j]**  now flows like oil --- SOLVED ..

Comment: Do you understand the difference between [][] and [,]?