# What is C# analog for C's two-dimensional array access like that: palette[ val & 3 ]?

Tags: c#, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

There is such array defined in C code: `u8 palette[4][4];`

Later some element accessed like that: `palette[ val & 3 ]`

In C code it's used like that: `memcpy(dest3+12, palette[ val & 3 ], 4);`

I don't understand what element is accessed via this code.
I tried to do same in C#, but it tells me `Wrong number of indices inside []; exptected 2`

Comment: What about `val % 3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, `palette` would just be a pointer, dereferencable at any time. `pallete[i]` is valid in C even for `u8 palette[4][4];`. However, when you declare `byte[,] palette = new byte[4,4];` in C#, you **must** properly use two indices to access the array. You might want to declare your `palette` in C# as a flattened-out array `byte[] palette = new byte[4*4]`and for `pallete[x,y]` write `palette[y*4 + x]`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand what's going on there.

Answer (score 4):

In C you can point to particular row in array, because C array is just sequence of items. Two subsequent arrays are just sequence of items again and that is why it is possible to access sub-array in C. That is why, you cannot get the size in array in C just from array pointer.

In C#, there are two types of "multidimensional" arrays: [Multidimensional arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) and [Jagged Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx).

Classic multi-dimensional cannot be access just by sub-index because array in C# is not just a sequence of items, but there is also a [header in which contain size of array, type pointer and sync block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589669/overhead-of-a-net-array). Two subsequent C# arrays will contains a header inside and it will not fulfill C# array format.

[Jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576759/what-is-a-jagged-array) is array of arrays and you can access sub-array with only sub-index in similar way to C#.

Equivalent code in C# would be:

```
byte[][] palette = new byte[4][];

for (int i = 0; i < palette.Length; i++)
{
   palette[i] = new byte[4];
}

byte[] destination = new byte[4];

int val = 1;
Array.Copy(palette[val & 3], 0, destination, 12, 4);
```

Be aware that in [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) are parameters in order: *destination*, *source* whereas in [Array.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx) are parameters in reverse order: *source*, *destination*

Comment: Thank for for good answer. I feel bad to took away accepted answer from another person and can't do that.

Comment: No problem, I maybe will get a badge for getting more votes than accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

palette is a square matix 4x4.

Using `val & 3` you are considering only first 2 bit of `val` variable value: that means you are accessing as max index `0x03`.

Whatever value has val only first 2 bits are taken into account.

Eg if val is 8 bit wise:

```
    val
0b11111100 & 3 = 0b00000000
0b11111101 & 3 = 0b00000001
0b11111110 & 3 = 0b00000010
0b11111111 & 3 = 0b00000011
```

Your code is accessing the array row by row.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, but I didn't understand another thing. How it were possible that two-dimensional array were accessed by single index. What index exactly were accessed like that. But `Maximilian Gerhardt` explained me this.