# How to make a Jagged Array?

Tags: c#, arrays

Thinking like a simple array:

```
Console.WriteLine("Number: ");
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

string[] strA = new string[x];

strA[0] = "Hello";
strA[1] = "World";    

for(int i = 0;i < x;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(strA[i]);
}
```

Now, how can I do it with a double array?

I've already tried this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Number 1: ");
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Number 2: ");
int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

// Got an error, right way string[x][];
// But how can I define the second array?
string[][] strA = new string[x][y]; 

strA[0][0] = "Hello";
strA[0][1] = "World";
strA[1][0] = "Thanks";
strA[1][1] = "Guys"; 

for(int i = 0;i < x;i++)
{
    for(int j = 0;i < y;i++)
    {
        // How can I see the items?
        Console.WriteLine(strA[i][j]); 
    }
}
```

If's there's a simpler way of doing this, i'll be happy to learn it.

It's only for knowledge, I'm studying double array for the first time, so have patience please :)

Here's my example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/PQblXH

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written?

Comment: Double array ? Like an array of double or a 2Dimention array ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Comment: Minor misunderstanding on your part, these are not double arrays they're called two dimensional arrays (there one, two, three ... n dimensional arrays). A double array would be an array of doubles

Comment: @xdtTransform if you look at the code you can see he means two dimensional arrays and not double arrays

Comment: I got this error when I define value to array (strA[0][1] ...), sorry i forgot to post that
[System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]  at Program.Main()

Comment: @MindSwipe, Retorical question to show the missleading title. And the documentation linked is all about multi dim array.

Comment: @MindSwipe, thanks, I didnt know that had this name

Comment: @MindSwipe it's not a two dimensional array, it's a jagged array. A two dimensional array would be `string[,]`

Comment: @LeoHenrique That pertinent information should be in your question.

Comment: You should have error using 0 and negative number and number that exceeds int max

Comment: X and Y are Size not index. How do you mentaly picture an array where one dim is 0 and the other is 1?

Comment: X is the size the array containing the other array of size Y. If X is 0 there is no array in the 1rst dimention. How could this nothing has a size of 1?

Comment: @xdtTransform, yeah its I size, Im trying to define the size, for after, see the results, one by one

Comment: Your fiddle code looks unrelated to your question.. You should take 5 minute and write in 3-4 simple sentences what you are trying to achieve. It will translate into code quite simply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a jagged array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576759/what-is-a-jagged-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are working with *jagged array* (i.e. array of array `string[][]`), not *2D* one (which is `string[,]`)

If you want to *hardcode*:

```
  string[][] strA = new string[][] { // array of array
    new string[] {"Hello", "World"}, // 1st line 
    new string[] {"Thanks", "Guys"}, // 2nd line
  };
```

in case you want to provide `x` and `y`:

```
  string[][] strA = Enumerable
    .Range(0, y)                   // y lines
    .Select(line => new string[x]) // each line - array of x items
    .ToArray();
```

Finally, if we want to initialize `strA` without *Linq* but good all `for` loop (unlike 2d array, *jagged* array can contain inner arrays of *different lengths*):

```
  // strA is array of size "y" os string arrays (i.e. we have "y" lines)
  string[][] strA = new string[y][];

  // each array within strA
  for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i)
    strA[i] = new string[x]; // is an array of size "x" (each line of "x" items)
```

**Edit:** Let's print out *jagged array* line after line:

Good old `for` loops

```
  for (int i = 0; i < strA.Length; ++i) {
    Console.WriteLine();

    // please, note that each line can have its own length
    string[] line = strA[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; ++j) {
      Console.Write(line[j]); // or strA[i][j]
      Console.Write(' ');     // delimiter, let it be space
    }
  }
```

Compact code:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.newLine, strA
    .Select(line => string.Join(" ", line))));
```

Comment: ok, but to define the items with an console.readline for example, how can i do?
string[][] strA = new string[][];
....

Comment: @LeoHenrique: since *jagged arra*y can contain arrays of *different lengths*, e.g. `new string[][] {new string[] {"a", "b", "c"}, new string[] {"p", "q"}};` we have to initialize it with a help of *loop* (if we don't want *Linq*)

Comment: @LeoHenrique: 1st index - "line", 2nd index - column; `strA[0][0] = "Hello"; strA[0][1] = "World";` let's print out the 1st line now: `Console.Write(string.Join(" ", strA[0]));`

Comment: for your last example: new string[][] {new string[] {"a", "b", "c"}, new string[] {"p", "q"}}; (its hard to understand for me) how i show this, like console.writeline(strA[...]), I want to see "a" and after "p"

Comment: @LeoHenrique: if you want to see `"a"` after `"p"` put it as `new string[][] {new string[] {"p", "a"}, new string[] {"q", "b"}, nes string[] {"c"}};` and you'll have lines `"p, a"`, `"q", "b"`, `"c"`

Comment: ok, one of my doubt solved, so each line I have a lenght, but to choose the 'column'?, i thinking this line 1 column 1: "a" line 2 column 1: "b", line 1 column 2: "p". Is my thought right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190511/discussion-between-dmitry-bychenko-and-leohenrique).

Answer (score 3):

You're using a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) instead of a [multidimensional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) one. Simply use `[,]` instead of `[][]`. You can then use it with `new string[x, y]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I want to learn how to do with this 2, I started with jagged array, so when I understand that, I'll try the multidimensional.
But thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to clarify thing in your head before writing code.
I will recommend writing in simple phrase what you want to do. The code in your fiddle go into every direction. I will address the code in the fiddle and not your questionas you have typo error and other issue that where not present in the fiddle while the fiddle has error that the question do not have.

To simplify the problem lets use clear understandable names. The 2d array will be an table, with rows and columns.

```
//  1/. Ask for 2table dim sizes.
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of rows:");
var x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of columns:");
var y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var table = new string[x, y];
```

You need to to declare your table before knowing its size.

```
// 2/. Fill the board
for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Enter the value of the cell [{row},{col}]");
        table[row, col] = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

`table.GetLength(0)` is equivalent to X, and `table.GetLength(1)` is equivalent to Y, and can be replace.

```
// 3/. Display the Table 
Console.Write("\n");
for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        Console.Write(table[row, col]);
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

For a 3x3 table with 00X, 0X0, X00 as inputs the result is

```
00X
0X0
X00
```

It works. You separate each cell when we display by simply adding a comma or a space. 
[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8PznAs)

And for Jagged Array:

```
//  1/. Ask for 2table dim sizes.
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of rows:");
var x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var table = new string[x][];

// 2/. Fill the board
for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Enter of the line n°{row}");
    var lineSize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    table[row] = new string[lineSize];
    for (int col = 0; col < table[row].Length; col++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Enter the value of the cell [{row},{col}]");
        table[row][col] = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}

// 3/. Display the Table 
Console.Write("\n");
for (int row = 0; row < table.Length; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < table[row].Length; col++)
    {
        Console.Write(table[row][col]);
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, very easy to understand, you and Dmitry Bychenko help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong variable in use:

```
for(int j = 0;i < y;i++) <- Should be j
{
    // How can I see the items?
    Console.WriteLine(strA[i][j]); 
}
```