# Difference between [,] and [][]

Tags: c#

In cSharp, a 2D array is written as `int[,] myArray = new int[,]`

However, it has come to my attention that `int[][] my Array = new int[][]` is also OK.

I am wondering if the 2 has any difference or it is the same.

Comment: The `[][]` approach lets you created a jagged array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576759/what-is-a-jagged-array/2576763#2576763

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)